# How to set association of two tables in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have three tables named Users, Baskets and Products.

Baskets table looks like:

id  |  quantities  |  productId  | userId

And Product table looks like:

id |  name  |  inventory

Users table looks like:

id  |  name

Here, the id in the Products table is the same as productId in the Baskets table.

What I want to do is to get all records from those tables with the relation of Products.id and Baskets.productId.

How to add association for the two tables?

I tried like this.

```
models.Baskets.hasOne(models.Products)
models.Products.belongsTo(models.Baskets, { foreignKey: 'productId', bindingKey: 'id' })

const getBaskets = async () => {
  try {
    return await models.Baskets.findAll({
      include: {
        model: models.Products
      }
    })
  } catch (error) {
    throw error
  }
}
```

But it didn't work for me.

What I expect is also not to have `BasketId` in Products table.

UPDATE: Baskets table has association with Users table.

So Baskets belongs to Users and Users has many Baskets.

```
models.Baskets.belongsTo(models.Users)
models.Users.hasMany(models.Baskets)
```

Answer (score 0):

If a product only belongs to one Basket, then the correct definition is:

Basket:

```
Id | quantities
```

Product:

```
Id | name | inventory | BascketId
```

But the most correct definition in my opinion is:

Product:

```
  Id, ...
```

Basket:

```
  Id, UserId
```

BasketProducts:

```
  ProductId, BasketId
```

Comment: Why should I have `basketId` in products? It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Actually, baskets table also belongs to users table.

Comment: @hotcakedev because your products belongs to your basket. Also you need to add ```UserId``` as foreign key to your basket model. Because your basket belongs to a user.